# difference between sampsize and classwt random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

Can some one explain the difference between `sampsize` and `classwt` in random forest part of R package. Is there any relation between these two parameters (assuming problem is a classification problem)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`sampsize` represents the sample size of the that is drawn. So, `sampsize = 10` would mean that 10 samples are drawn. `classwt` is weighting of the classes. This can be used for a weighted random forest. For example, you can use this to weight more recent data as opposed to older data (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83104/weighting-more-recent-data-in-random-forest-model?rq=1)). Having said that, downsampling (which is reducing the sample size), is seemingly as effective as weighting the classes (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157714/r-package-for-weighted-random-forest-classwt-option)), so you can, but needn't use both.